# Test that mempool reattempts delivery of locally submitted transaction

Tags: mempool, regtest, broadcast

Test: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/test/functional/mempool_unbroadcast.py

I am trying this manually with below steps:

1. Run two nodes (regtest):

Node1:

```
bitcoind -port=18333 -rpcport=18332 -datadir="/home/prayank/node1" -conf="/home/prayank/node1/bitcoin.conf"
```

Node2:

```
bitcoind -port=18444 -rpcport=18443 -datadir="/home/prayank/node2" -conf="/home/prayank/node2/bitcoin.conf"
```

2. `bitcoin.conf`:

Node1:

```
regtest=1
server=1
listen=1

debug=mempool

regtest.rpcport=18332
rpcuser=user3
rpcpassword=password3

fallbackfee=0.0001

regtest.addnode=127.0.0.1:18444
```

Node2:

```
regtest=1
server=1
listen=1

debug=mempool

regtest.rpcport=18443
rpcuser=user3
rpcpassword=password3

fallbackfee=0.0001
```

3. Everything looks okay until Line [`68`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/da1c0c64fd094880712d1c4167ad9eb3bb6ffcc6/test/functional/mempool_unbroadcast.py#L68)

How would I do this without running this python code?

```
        # fast forward into the future & ensure that the second node has the txns
        node.mockscheduler(MAX_INITIAL_BROADCAST_DELAY)
        self.sync_mempools(timeout=30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mockscheduler` is a hidden RPC. This means that it will not be displayed when using the `help` command, but you can still use it by just calling it as usual. E.g. to do the same thing as this line in the test, you would do

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest mockscheduler 900
```

`sync_mempools()` is a function which just waits for the `getrawmempool` results of multiple nodes to match. You can just do that manually.

Comment: Interesting. This is like hidden gem.